# How to retrieve certain keys and values from json format data present as a column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which look like the below one (Column names - Date, Error message, message)

```
data = """Date|Error|message
   26/11/19   |   unauthorized access | {"eventVersion":"1.05","userIdentity":"type":"IAMUser","principalId":"AIDAIETZDDDVS36MMCHPS","arn":"arn:aws:iam::819490967212:user/IAMAdmin","accountId":"819490967212","accessKeyId":"ASIA35TLXZ2WPIBTBWP2","userName":"IAMAdmin","sessionContext":{"sessionIssuer":{},"webIdFederationData":{},"attributes":{"mfaAuthenticated":"false","creationDate":"2019-12-19T03:14:04Z"}}"""
```

---

```
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),sep='|)

print(df)
Date        Error   message
0   26/11/19    unauthorized access {"eventVersion":"1.05","userIdentity":"type":...
```

Each row of the message column has data similar to json format.

How to retrieve certain keys and its respective values `("userName", "account ID")` from the "message" column so that those keys can be new columns.

Trying with python but failed to retrieve

Comment: your json is not valid,
this line "userIdentity":"type":"IAMUser",

Comment: is your json exactly like this? it doesn't seem like valid json?

Answer (score 0):

```
df['userName'] = df['message'].apply(lambda x: x.get('userName'))
df['account'] = df['message'].apply(lambda x: x.get('account'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
json or pandas

```
import json
#some JSON:
x =  '{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'

# parse x:
y = json.loads(x)



# the result is a Python dictionary:
print(y["age"])
```

or you can use pandas.read_json()
it works the same way but you should play with the orientation. check it out here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html